# Xrandr not detecting HDMI/Displayport inputs on Ubuntu 18.04. Default graphics renderer is also set to llvmpipe instead of intel

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi, xrandr

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm experiencing issue with intel gpu drivers. I don't have nvidia gpu, only integrated one. As you can see below, xrandr does not detect any hdmi/displayport inputs, thus my external monitors don't work.
Also, in system settings->details->about for graphics it says **llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits)** while it should say intel.

**This happens for me only on ubuntu 18.04, everything works fine on 20.04**. It should probably be some driver/kernel incompatibility, however I don't use ubuntu too much and would appreciate help. **Ubuntu is running in dual boot with windows 10 usin grub as bootload.**

Specs:

```
Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen2
Ubuntu: 18.04.5
Processor: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8 
kernel: 5.4.0-66-generic
```

xrandr output:

```
 xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
 Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
 default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
 1920x1080     77.00*
```

lshw output:

```
   sudo lshw -c video
   [sudo] password for karlo: 
    *-display UNCLAIMED       
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:601c000000-601cffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

lspci  output:

```
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01) (prog-if 00         [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5088
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
Memory at 601c000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
I/O ports at 4000 [disabled] [size=64]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: llvmpipe means you do not have any 3D support (like transparency) . And it will not support any external monitors. So it seems your (new) GPU is not supported by the 18.04 kernel and its drivers. Use 20.04 instead - as you mentioned above, since it obviously has the drivers you need.

Comment: .@kanehekili I figured that might be the problem. However, I need to use 18.04 in order to use ros melodic. Thought there might be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you'd install Ubuntu 20.04- knowing that you want to run ROS melodic - you could then install instead the Ubuntu 20 Version named:

`ROS Noetic`

That software has a different name for each Ubuntu Version. For Ubuntu 20.04 it is called **ROS Noetic**. So look it up [here](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu) how to install it. Then you'd have your hardware supported and your ROS app.